# BCP utility login error

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am using the following command to import data into sql server:

```
bcp 
dbo.traderprodmap in c:temp\data.txt
 -c -t -S "SQLTRADERQA\TRADERQA" 
-d trader -Uabcprod123 -Pabc&prod
```

I get the following error:

> SQLstate 28000 and nativeerror 18456
>   Login failed for user abcprod123

I have invoked the  above command thru administrator mode. Double checked username and pwd . 
Can someone pls point out the issue here?

Comment: Why you are useing -t without field_term? Try to not use -t

Comment: Did that , gives the same error

Comment: Check SQL server error log for the cause of this error. It's authentication error, it has nothing to do with "-t"

Comment: -U "abcprod123" -P "abc&prod"

Answer (score 0):

Escape the & in your password.  Editted...

The ampersand is a special character in the windows command line.

Try escaping it with the Hat/Carrot (^).  so Pabc^&prod

Comment: Tried that , is there perhaps another way to escape &

Comment: Editted.  Try ^ or ".  I know I've run into this before when using an ssis package generating a command line.  checking files...